# Conditional and unconditional expectation for the variance of error term in linear regression

Tags: regression, self-study

I'm working through the book [Introductory Econometrics](https://economics.ut.ac.ir/documents/3030266/14100645/Jeffrey_M._Wooldridge_Introductory_Econometrics_A_Modern_Approach__2012.pdf) and stumbled across a statement regarding the variance of the error term, $u$, of a linear regression model, $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + u$.

To give some context, two assumptions were introduced beforehand:

1. Zero conditional mean, i.e. $E(u|x) = 0$, and
2. Homoskedasticity, i.e. $Var(u|x) = \sigma^2$.

Then, the argument goes on as follows:

> Because $Var(u|x) = E(u^2|x) - [E(u|x)]^2$ and $E(u|x) = 0$, $\sigma^2 = E(u^2|x)$, **which means $\sigma^2$ is also the *unconditional* expectation of $u^2$**.

While I understand the first part of the sentence, I have no idea where the bolded part comes from. It seems to say that *because* $E(u^2|x)=\sigma^2$ (i.e. the *conditional* expectation of $u^2$), it follows that $E(u^2) = \sigma^2$ (i.e. the *un*conditional expectation of $u^2$).
I might be missing something very basic here, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It follows from the [law of iterated expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation): the expected value of the conditional expected value of $u$ given $X$ is the same as the expected value of $u$.

$$E[u^2] = E[E[u^2|X]] = E[\sigma^2] = \sigma^2$$

Comment: Wooldridge, _Introductory Econometrics_, Appendix B, Property CE.4, page 687.